# Support vector machine (SVM) hyper plane formula

Tags: web-applications, classification, svm, libsvm

I'm working on image classification system, i used sift and support vector machine. I want to make it a web application using java applet, How can i use SVM results to classify new images? 
Is there a formula for svm hyper plane that i can use? or anything else can be used to classify.
actually i calculated the sift for all images and i want to have a web application that a user can browse an image from predefined images (which it's sift is calculated) and classify to see the results.
PS: i did the training phase using MATLAB i just want the final decision for classification of new images.

Answer (score 0):

Just a basic thought - if you already have *predefined* images, with **precalculated** sifts, why not **preclassify** them too?

The classification "formula" for SVM can be of two types:

a) for linear case, assuming that you have `w` (features weight vector) and `b` (threshold)

```
f(x)=sgn( w'x + b )
```

b) for kernelized case, assuming that you have `alpha` (dual coeffficients), `sv` (support vectors), `K` (used kernel function) and `b` (threshold)

```
f(x)=sgn( sum_i alpha_i K(sv_i,x) + b )
```